# Flutter Monitor FileUpload progress using the http package

Tags: file, http, flutter, file-upload, progress

I have been using the following code to upload files on my server as it is doing the job but i want to monitor the Upload Progress Percentage during the opration and Update the UI accordingly to reflect the prgress to the user

```
uploadFile({File imageFile, String refCode}) async {
    // open a bytestream
    var stream =
        new http.ByteStream(DelegatingStream.typed(imageFile.openRead()));
    // get file length
    var length = await imageFile.length();

    // string to uri
    var uri = Uri.parse(
        'http://-------------/api/FilesUploadB/?refCode=$refCode');

    // create multipart request
    var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);

    // multipart that takes file
    var multipartFile = new http.MultipartFile('file', stream, length,
        filename: basename(imageFile.path));

    // add file to multipart
    request.files.add(multipartFile);

    // send
    var response = await request.send();

    // listen for response
    response.stream.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((value) {
      print(value);
    });

    //return response.
  }
```

NOTE that the `value` in the listen is getting me the final return from the WebAPI on the server.
how to achieve that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Take a look at this [example](https://github.com/salk52/Flutter-File-Upload-Download/blob/master/upload_download_app/lib/services/file_service.dart#L117) on GitHub. It demonstrates how you can access the current upload progress of your file.

Comment: Worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's not working. some methods are deprciated i guess. Like request.addStream and request.close.. do you have any other alternative