# How do I track progress for a Multipart data task in Dart?

Tags: dart, http

I have

```
http.MultipartRequest request = ...
final res = await request.send();
```

But I want to listen to progress. How can I do that?

ChatGPT tells me to `response.stream.listen` after the `await req.send()`, but that does not seem to be right!

Edit: Using `StreamedResponse` returns the progress of the response, not of the request unfortunately.

Comment: maybe you can map your filestream progress instead.

Comment: Good idea. I have multiple files as byte arrays currently which makes it difficult. It kinda works, but each file is one step. As one file is 90% of the data progress jumps 90% at a time..

Comment: have you seen this code https://github.com/salk52/Flutter-File-Upload-Download/blob/master/upload_download_app/lib/services/file_service.dart#L117 ? (ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61383244/flutter-monitor-fileupload-progress-using-the-http-package#61385302)

Comment: It uses the .finalize method (from http package) + a StreamTransformer to track the progress

Comment: I am using sth similar, but it chunks progress per file, and that is quite a low resolution (see my previous commit). It is not streamed from a file though, maybe that would fix it.