# how send files to API with http package and have a onSendProgress like Dio package

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

we have a post method and on that User send some data like Images and text or something else

and I need when user select images and click on button to send data to API

show progressBar about uploading files on UI and How much data has been sent and how much is left

on Dio that to easy you can use onSendProgress

on http Package I need somthing like onSendProgress in Dio package

```
  function() async{
    try{

      var uri = Uri.parse('MY API');
      http.MultipartRequest request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', uri);

      request.fields['subject'] = newDemandSubjectController.text;
      request.fields['text'] = newDemandBodyController.text;

      List<http.MultipartFile> newList = <http.MultipartFile>[];

      for(var image in selectedImages){
        File imageFile =  File(image.path);
        var stream = http.ByteStream(imageFile.openRead());
        var length = imageFile.lengthSync();
        var multipartFile = http.MultipartFile("images[]", stream, length,
            filename: '${DateTime.now()}.${image.path.split('.').last}');
        newList.add(multipartFile);
      }

      request.headers.assignAll({
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $USER_TOKEN'
      });

      request.files.addAll(newList);

      var response = await request.send();

      print(response.contentLength);
      print(response.stream);

      response.stream.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((value) {
    print(value);
    });

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print('done');

    } else {
    print('failed');
    }

    }catch(e){
    return Future.error(jsonDecode(e.toString()));
    }
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter Monitor FileUpload progress using the http package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61383244/flutter-monitor-fileupload-progress-using-the-http-package)

Comment: nop thats not work :(

Answer (score 0):

**Hey, could you try this:**
I listen to the chunk through the stream.

```
void uploadFiles() async {
      try {
        var uri = Uri.parse('MY API');
        var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', uri);
    
        request.fields['subject'] = newDemandSubjectController.text;
        request.fields['text'] = newDemandBodyController.text;
    
        List<http.MultipartFile> newList = [];
    
        for (var image in selectedImages) {
          File imageFile = File(image.path);
          var stream = http.ByteStream(imageFile.openRead());
          var length = imageFile.lengthSync();
          var multipartFile = http.MultipartFile(
            "images[]",
            stream,
            length,
            filename: '${DateTime.now()}.${image.path.split('.').last}',
          );
          newList.add(multipartFile);
        }
    
        request.headers.addAll({
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $USER_TOKEN',
        });
    
        request.files.addAll(newList);
    
        var client = http.Client();
        var streamedRequest = await client.send(request);
    
        var total = streamedRequest.contentLength ?? 0;
        var count = 0;
    
        streamedRequest.stream.listen(
          (List<int> chunk) {
            count += chunk.length;
    
            var progress = count / total;
    
            updateUIProgress(progress);
    
          },
          onDone: () {
            client.close();
          },
          onError: (error) {
            client.close();
          },
          cancelOnError: true,
        );
    
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }
    }
    
    void updateUIProgress(double progress) {
      print(progress);
    }
```

Comment: print: =====> I/flutter (27654): Infinity